# Sampling for quality control

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, sample-size, descriptive-statistics, quality-control

I would like to do some quality control study for a set of manufactured components. For a given set, I can draw several samples. Each drawn sample can be either good or bad. My plan is to create a probability index that can indicate whether this set is good or bad. For instance, 9 of 10 samples are evaluated as good. Then a naïve index for the original set can be 0.9.

Are there any statistically sound methods to build this kind of index? I think “sample theory” maybe related, but I am not sure which method will be the best fit so that I can explore without reading whole book without any target.  The method should also be based on the size of the set. In practice, the size of the set can vary between 500 to 10000.  Certainly, we can have some prior knowledge on the quality of set.  For instance, it is very likely that the set can be good or bad.

Comment: There are indeed established methods to address this kind of problems, usually discussed under the name “Statistical process control”. Books on sampling methods would be more difficult to relate directly to such applications. Statistical decision theory is also relevant.

Comment: Let's start with these considerations: what exactly does it mean for a set to be "good" or "bad"? What actions do you propose to make from your "index"? If your index is not perfect and happens to mischaracterize goodness or badness in a particular case, what would be the cost of making such an error? Is your study online--in real time--or is it retrospective, intended to evaluate the quality after the fact?

Comment: One thing to note is that, against what intuition suggests, the size of the whole set/population/run/batch does not always matter.

Comment: @whuber, "good" or "bad" was kind of rough concepts here. In my case, "bad" means that we are going to have some economic loss. The exact number of loss is case-by-case. For a brainstorming, we can say the loss will be $100K. The study is more like a prediction or a pre-evaluation.

Comment: What matters is the *quantitative* connection between the sample results and "goodness" or "badness". What is that connection?

Comment: @Laurans, could you specify which part/methodology of statistical process control maybe a potential candidate for this  kind of problem?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the reply. In my original post, I mentioned a naive connection between the sample result and "goodness" or "badness". If one of ten samples gets an evaluation of "fail", we can say the original set is good. Thus, 0.9 can be thought of a threshold. I would like to know are there any sound statistical methodology to design this threshold?

Comment: Yes--provided you give a quantitative way to connect the sampling results to the goodness of the population! Until you do that, you can't even get started and you'll just go around in circles. *E.g.*, in some applications the entire population is "bad" if *any single member* is bad. More often, the entire population is "bad" if *more than a predetermined proportion of its members are bad.* In other applications, the population is "bad" if the *average* of some attribute of its members is below some threshold. Or maybe it's bad if its *standard deviation* is larger than some threshold, etc.

Comment: @whuber, so my understanding is that this "quantitative connection" is kind of arbitrary. Or, it is just decided by the quality control person. The statistical quality control is just a statistical analysis based on this given quantitative connection. We cannot have a scientific way to design this quantitative connection.

Comment: It is not in the least arbitrary, but there is an extra element that must be brought to bear: you need to quantify the consequences of making errors. If you know, even approximately, what it costs to overlook quality problems and what it costs to react prematurely to spurious signals that are unrelated to quality problems, then you can optimize the design of the statistical sampling.  If you do not know these things and you simply make up sampling rules, such as your 9/10 rule, that is tantamount to using a non-optimal procedure and you will (perhaps unknowingly) pay a price.

Comment: @user785099 Well, no, I have no idea and besides it's going to depend on the answers to the questions asked by whuber. That's why I did not submit an answer, just some keywords which might help you locate more relevant material. I am afraid that reading a whole book might still be in order, not only to find out about specific techniques but also to help you think about all this more systematically!

Comment: @user785099 my business is importing products from China and my situation is far less grave than yours. I choose to test 100% of the products we sell. Sounds like 1 or 2 losses for your company would cost more than 100% testing. My latest situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269638